# Snapdのエラーを解決したい: cannot communicate with server

Tags: linux

## エラーの詳細

アプリをsnapでインストールしようとすると下記のエラーが出る。

```py
$ sudo apt install snapd
$ sudo snap install mini-diary

error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/mini-diary: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

## バージョン

```
$ snap --version
snap    2.37.4-1+b1
snapd   unavailable
series  -
```

## OS

MX Linux

```py
$ cat /etc/debian_version
10.4

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
PRETTY_NAME="MX 19.2 patito feo"
DISTRIB_ID=MX
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.2 
DISTRIB_CODENAME="patito feo"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="MX 19.2 patito feo"
```

### インストールした際の画面

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 追記でインストールされた "snap" パッケージは (紛らわしいですが) "snapd" パッケージと別物のようです。

Answer (score 0):

snapd が起動していないように見えます。MX Linux の環境が手元に無いので試していませんが、`systemctl start snapd.service` (systemd の場合) や `service snapd start` (sysVinit の場合) などの方法でデーモンを起動させれば動かないでしょうか。

Comment: 試してみたところ`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: ホストが落ちています
`と表示されます

Comment: ということは init としては sysVinit をお使いでしょうか？　init としてお使いのシステムの方法に則ってデーモンを起動する必要があると思っています。

Comment: initはおそらくsystemdだと思います。

Comment: であれば上記のエラーメッセージが出るのはおかしいですね。おそらく sysVinit が使われているのではないかと思いますが……。sysVinit の場合のコマンドも追記してみたのでお試しください。先頭に sudo が必要かもしれません。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。試してみたのですが次のような結果が出ました。`snapd: unrecognized service
`

Comment: うーん謎ですね……。apt install 時に何かしらエラーなど出てないかログを確認いただけますか。可能であれば再インストールを試してください。現状私だとすぐには分かりそうにないです、すいません。

Comment: ありがとうございました。一応purgeして再インストールした後の画像を追記しておきました。

Answer (score 0):

自分も同じ現象に悩まされてきました。Ubuntu 20.04です。
[こちらのサイト](https://qiita.com/matarillo/items/f036a9561a4839275e5f)を参考に、以下の方法で snap を使えるようになりました。

但し事前に以下のコマンドを実行する必要が有りました。

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade -y
$ sudo apt install daemonize
```

[Running Snaps on WSL2 (Insiders only for now)](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/running-snaps-on-wsl2-insiders-only-for-now/13033)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたんですが、結果は変わらなかったです。daemonizeをインストールして、snapdをインストールしただけなのですが、やり方を間違えているでしょうか？

Comment: Running Snaps on WSL2 (Insiders only for now)　のリンク先の通りにやってみてください。そのサイト中の、OPTIONALの前までやって出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

snaps には, systemdが必要そうです。もう一度 環境を確認してみるのも良いかも

```sh
$ systemctl status snapd.service
 snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-25 05:36:01 JST; 4 days ago
TriggeredBy:  snapd.socket
   Main PID: 1254 (snapd)
      Tasks: 19 (limit: 18118)

$ snap version
snap    2.49.1
snapd   2.49.1
series  16
ubuntu  20.10
kernel  5.8.0-48-generic
```

Ubuntuでは, 上記のメッセージ(とログ)が出ました

参考:

- [SOLVED - Cannot install snaps on Linux MX19 patito feo](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/solved-cannot-install-snaps-on-linux-mx19-patito-feo/14976)
- [MX Linux(Debian)でSnapdが動かない?](https://nyakki-yossi.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/03/18/021440)